# Setting SDK Location in Netbeans

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I'm having some trouble setting the Android SDK Location in Netbeans. I have installed the SDK and even run a virtual device in it, but for some reason Netbeans is not recognizing the SDK.  Here is the location of my SDK:
[image]

And when I have this entered in Netbeans:

[image]

The 'OK' or 'Apply' buttons still aren't clickable. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? All the tutorials I've been following havn't had trouble at this point...
Thanks!

Comment: did u try to navigate into the sub "sdk" directory ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the default Android SDK path used by Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330176/what-is-the-default-android-sdk-path-used-by-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `c:\Android\Android-SDK\sdk` is the location that you need.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51585165/11456650

I found it on my computer at `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk`