# What is the default Android SDK path used by Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, path, sdk

When using Android Studio to download the Android SDK, what is the default path where it downloads to?

I'm interested in knowing the paths for Linux, Mac, and Windows.

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176594/android-sdk-location

Comment: @Deming That link you provide refers to Xamarin not being able to find the Android SDK. This one is about the default location to where Android Studio downloads the SDK when not provided a custom path.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From searching in the web it seems to be:

- Linux: `~/Android/Sdk`
- Mac: `~/Library/Android/sdk`
- Windows: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk`

I find it odd to have inconsistent paths and even the lower/upper case for Linux and Mac ("Sdk" vs "sdk"), but it seems to be this way...

Comment: It's actually a capital "Sdk" on Windows as well, it's just case-insensitive by default, so it doesn't matter. I'm not sure if the lowercase "sdk" is actually correct on Mac. It might be a similar situation as Windows, where it's actually "Sdk", but it's case-insensitive by default.

Comment: It was like that 3 years ago when I posted the answer. Things might have changed meanwhile, which makes sense, in order to make the paths more standard between the various platforms.

Answer (score 18):

**Linux** /home/AccountName/Android/Sdk

Comment: be more concise next time

Answer (score 15):

Click this icon in Android Studio for the Android SDK manager:
[image]

And your android sdk location will be here:
[image]

I hope its helpful for you!

Comment: I need to know the actual paths on all the platforms, not "how to" find them out. This is because I do not have access to all the 3 mentioned platforms, yet I need to make some tools that download the SDK and put them in the correct folder, where Android studio would also download it to, so that if the Android Studio is installed in the future the SDK is already there.

Comment: For Linux: http://www.itzgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Linux-Mint-12-NB-Choose-SDK-Location.png

Comment: @Arsian Developer those don't look like Android Studio screenshots. Ok, the first one looks like a really old Android Studio version, but I'm pretty sure the Linux one is Netbeans which didn't even ever receive official Android support.
In any case, both of them seem to have custom paths, rather than the default one.

Answer (score 2):

Actually in windows it is C:\Users\UserAccount\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Just replace UserAccount with your actual user account name